# How to use Context within discord.ext.tasks loop in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So what I've been trying to do is to create a task that collects data from API and sends it to specific channel in the guild every day at the same time.

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=60)
    async def deals(self):
        if datetime.now().hour == 12:
            session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
            request = await session.get('url')
            deals_list = await request.json()
            embeds_list: list = []

            # ...
            # Here is code responsible for assembling the embeds list to send from gathered data, which is irrelevant
            # ...
            
            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                try:
                    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name='category')
                    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='channel', category=category)
                    await channel.purge()
                    for e in embeds_list:
                        await channel.send(embed=e)
                except discord.errors.Forbidden:
                    continue
                except discord.errors.NotFound:
                    await create_missing_channels(guild) # my function
```

So as you can see I wanted to make this task run on every guild that the bot is connected to. The problem is that without the Context, I need to use the loop to iterate through every guild and execute the same code on each of them, which is probably not the most efficient solution. If I were to run this on 100 guilds at the same time, it would take ages.

Is there any possible way to use Context within task, or do you see any other possibility to handle task as this one without iterating over each guild to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no `Context` in a `Task`. What you *could* do, however, is iterate through all guilds on startup and store what you need somewhere in your bot as a `botvar`. You could run this as a task that only executes once when it starts:

```
self.bot.channel_dic = {}
for guild in self.bot.guilds:
    try:
        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name='category')
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='channel', category=category)
        self.bot.channel_dic[guild.id] = channel.id
    except discord.errors.NotFound:
        await create_missing_channels(guild)
```

Now you have a dictionary mapping every guild's `id` to their corresponding `Channel` that you wanted to send a message to, meaning in the future you can just iterate over those instead of having to use `utils.get` twice for each one to find them all again.

Do remember to also add the channel created in the `create_missing_channels` function into the dictionary in case it didn't exist, otherwise it'll be missing.

```
for guild in self.bot.channel_dic:
    channel = self.bot.channel_dic[guild]
    try:
        await channel.purge()
        for e in embeds_list:
            await channel.send(embed=e)
    except discord.errors.Forbidden:
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but unfortunately this wasn't what I was looking for, since with your solution you still have to iterate over something, in this case over dict, and my problem was that I needed to somehow make all the iterations happen at once, so the same code would be executed on every guild at the same time. Luckily I found out the solution and posted it in separate comment.

Comment: My bad, I thought you mainly wanted to avoid having to `get` those channels every single time. Good that you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so my problem was that I was iterating over guilds, so whevener the task was going to start, it would execute the code on each guild separately, one by one, which would make it take a long time if there were a lot of guilds to handle.

If anyone was looking for the possible solution, I managed to solve it with asyncio. I put the logic code in separate function and created new task loop that handles it with asyncio.gather():

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=60)
async def deals(self):
    if datetime.now().hour == 12:
        coroutines = [deals_task(guild) for guild in self.bot.guilds]
        await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood this.
But if for every guild(server) your bot is in you create a class that is separate from discord.py but still using the functionality of it. (Don’t rely on discord.py classes, use them in your application instead.). create a function in each classinstance for your loop.
Then you iterate through the class of instances and start a loop for each that fits the description.

Create a decorated loop function in the class
GlobalGuildClass[guild].loop()

For gid in GlobalGuildClass
GlobalGuildClass[gid].loop.start()

Then on_ready() iterate through GlobalGuildClass and start the loop for each.
?
I don’t know if it works. but in theory it could work.
Perhaps not pythonic.